# Objective C NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, subset, nsmutabledictionary

I have a question about NSMutableDictionary,

Let's say I have two set of NSMutableDictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *oddNumber
NSMutableDictionary *randomNumber
```

Is there a function to check value of randomNumber is SUBSET of value of oddNumber or not?

Comment: No there isn't; you'd have to write it yourself, or coax someone on here to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
    NSMutableDictionary *oddNumber;
    NSMutableDictionary *randomNumber;
    // Create arrays
    NSArray *arroddNumber = [oddNumber allValues];
    NSArray *arrrandomNumber = [oddNumber allValues];


    // Turn the arrays into sets and intersect the two sets
    NSMutableSet *oddNumberSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:arroddNumber];
    NSMutableSet *randomNumbersSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:arrrandomNumber];

    [oddNumberSet intersectSet:randomNumbersSet];

    // The Values present in both arrays
    NSLog(@"Common Values : %@", oddNumberSet);
```

Comment: Sir is this function intersectSet: expensive? Is there any other function have less work load?

Comment: @Neo If performance matters to you, surely you have a way to test if this solution is fast enough for you, right?

Comment: I know there a lot of function run with different algorithm, but i know have one is faster for big data to compute and some small data run faster with another function

Comment: here an example: http://www.academia.edu/2422025/An_Algorithm_for_Dynamic_Subset_and_Intersection_Testing

Comment: Great! Enjoy coding@Neo

Comment: Will this work when different keys have the same value?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the values for each dictionary using the `values` method.  This returns an array. You could then convert these arrays to sets, which have methods to check if one set is a subset of another.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the values that you have. Make sure they have an isEqual: method and a hash method, so you can add them to a set. Create an NSSet with all values of the second dictionary, then iterate through the first dictionary and check which values are in the set.

Note that creating a set with N values takes O (N) time if the values have a decent hash function, and looking up a value in a set is constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Short:

`BOOL isSubset = [[oddNumber dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[randomNumber allKeys]] isEqualToDictionary:randomNumber]`

or faster:

```
__block BOOL isSubset = YES;
[randomNumber enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
    id value = [oddNumber objectForKey:key];
    if (!value || ![value isEqual:obj]) {
        isSubset = NO;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```